# URL redirection issue using PK

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

Hi guys I have a primary key issue with the following error : django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'addteam' not found. 'addteam' is not a valid view function or
 pattern name.

My app is simple : a user create a project then arrive to a page in a detail page with a button in order to invite user using mails ... the thing is I get the error just after creating the project

Here is my code :

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from website import views

app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^candidateIndex/$', views.CandidateIndex.as_view(), name='candidate_index'),
    url(r'^HRcreate/$', views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='HR_create'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/invite/$',views.create_invite, name='addteam'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .forms import InviteForm
from invitations.models import Invitation
from .models import project
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your views here.

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'index.html'

class CandidateIndex(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'candidateIndex.html'

class HRIndex(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'HRindex.html'

class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = project
    fields = ['project_name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'


def create_invite(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        invite_form = InviteForm(data=request.POST)
        if invite_form.is_valid():
            email1 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email1']
            email2 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email2']
            email3 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email3']
            email4 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email4']
            email5 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email5']
            for i in invite_form.cleaned_data:
                invite = Invitation.create(i)
                invite.send_invitation(request)
            print("The mail was went")
            #return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk} )
        else:
            print("Your form is not valid")
    else:
        invite_form = InviteForm()
    return render(request, 'team_invite.html', {'invite_form': invite_form})
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name


class Team(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(project)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

project_details.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Welcome to your Project {{project.project_name}} Detail page</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="invite-team">
      <a href="{% url 'website:addteam'%}">GOGO</a>
  </div>
</div>




{% endblock%}
```

the error :
In template /Users/raphaelbendenoun/Documents/SoftScores_project_Final/templates/base.html, error at line 8
Reverse for 'addteam' not found. 'addteam' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

--> line 8 is the bootsrap link ...

Comment: None of the code you have posted is attempting to do a reverse for "addteam". You need to show the full traceback, plus the code which is actually causing the error (which will be indicated by the traceback).

Comment: (Plus, your view is nonsense; what are all those `emailX` variables for?)

Comment: Hi Daniel thx for your answer, I added the html file where I ask the url addteam

Comment: the EmailX variable is a test for the invitation app : https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line below Indicates that your view is accepting a primary key to the project model.

```
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/invite/$',views.create_invite, name='addteam'),
```

However your view below does not indicated your using the project model in it.

```
def create_invite(request, pk):
```

So change

```
 def create_invite(request, pk):
```

to

```
 def create_invite(request):
```

and

```
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/invite/$',views.create_invite, name='addteam')
```

to

```
url(r'^project/invite/$',views.create_invite, name='addteam')
```

Hopefully your template should then work.

If you need to pass a primary key to a view, in your template you need to do

```
<a href="{% url 'website:addteam' pk_key_value %}">GOGO</a>
```

Where pk_key_value should be a variable with the primary key of the model object.

Below link will give you more clarity.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/

Also for sending emails refer 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/

You dont seem to have 'imported from django.core.mail'

Comment: Hi Keegan thx for your answer ;) It worked. My question is how can I link a project to an invitation list ?  I mean that I would like that for each project there is an invite ..

Comment: That would be more of a design related question. You can generate an email Token to be sent to users who while clicking on the same would gain access to that particular project. Below link should help you with email tokens. https://farhadurfahim.github.io/post/django-registration-with-confirmation-email/